# ripple transaction max amount

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

If I send a query

```
{"method":"sign","params":[{"secret":"shU9DWXZ1bhtaZRipiCedMUn1B2Gg","tx_json":{"Amount":9000000000,"Account":"rPa8RMPnEJxW4dpkJhnqj7GQYUB9PQ5gEW","Destination":"rH7k1edohG2XCBuTiB8RrMaKRgi2wNkXYg","DestinationTag":100008276,"TransactionType":"Payment"}}]}
```

The testnet Ripple server (https://s.altnet.rippletest.net:51234) give me

```
Unable to parse request: * Line 1, Column 90 '9000000000' exceeds the allowable range.
```

How can I send more than 9000 XRP at one transaction?

Comment: For some reason questions about Ripple are being voted down. The welcome text states clearly that this Stack Exchange Site is also for Ripple

"Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, ZCash, Dogecoin, and NXT.

Please note that Ethereum and Monero have launched their own Stack Exchange sites."

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this issue still a problem? But Sending the amount property as a string worked for me.

Comment: In the question the amount was passed without quotation marks, which may be interpreted as a number instead of a string. This answer should probably be a little more elaborate, but I think it's actually an attempt to answer.

Answer (score 0):

9000000000 is not a legal amount. Getting your amounts correct is extremely important and you *definitely* don't want to even think about using JSON integers because their representation range is unspecified.

As the [documentation for specifying currency amounts](https://xrpl.org/basic-data-types.html#specifying-currency-amounts) says, amounts of XRP are represented as strings, not integers. The number of integer drops is specified as a string, with each drop being one millionth of an XRP. So you probably wanted `"9000000000"` to specify 9,000,000,000 drops or 9,000 XRP.